# How to select distinct rows from a Spark Window partition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a sample DF with duplicate rows like this:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+----+-----------+-------+----------+
|ID                  |CL_ID               |NBR |DT         |TYP    |KEY       |
+--------------------+--------------------+----+-----------+-------+----------+
|1000031075_20190422 |10017157594301072477|10  |2019-04-24 |N      |0000000000|
|1000031075_20190422 |10017157594301072477|10  |2019-04-24 |N      |0000000000|
|1006473016_20190421 |10577157412800147475|11  |2019-04-21 |N      |0000000000|
|1006473016_20190421 |10577157412800147475|11  |2019-04-21 |N      |0000000000|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+-----------+-------+----------+
```

`val w = Window.partitionBy($"ENCOUNTER_ID")`

Using the above Spark Window partition, is it possible to select distinct rows? I am expecting the output DF as:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+----+-----------+-------+----------+
|ID                  |CL_ID               |NBR |DT         |TYP    |KEY       |
+--------------------+--------------------+----+-----------+-------+----------+
|1000031075_20190422 |10017157594301072477|10  |2019-04-24 |N      |0000000000|
|1006473016_20190421 |10577157412800147475|11  |2019-04-21 |N      |0000000000|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+-----------+-------+----------+
```

I don't want to use `DF.DISTINCT` or `DF.DROPDUPLICATES` as it would involve shuffling. 
I prefer not to use lag or lead because, in real-time, the order of rows can't be guaranteed.

Comment: Window functions also need shuffling... so  I would use `dropDuplicates("ID")`,  `distinct` is more expensive because it compares all columns

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878994/remove-duplicates-without-shuffle-spark

Answer (score 0):

Window function also shuffle data. So if your all columns are duplicate then `df.dropDuplicates` will be better option to use. If your use case want to use `Window` function then you can use below approach.

```
scala> df.show()
+-------------------+--------------------+---+----------+---+----------+
|                 ID|               CL_ID|NBR|        DT|TYP|       KEY|
+-------------------+--------------------+---+----------+---+----------+
|1000031075_20190422|10017157594301072477| 10|2019-04-24|  N|0000000000|
|1000031075_20190422|10017157594301072477| 10|2019-04-24|  N|0000000000|
|1006473016_20190421|10577157412800147475| 11|2019-04-21|  N|0000000000|
|1006473016_20190421|10577157412800147475| 11|2019-04-21|  N|0000000000|
+-------------------+--------------------+---+----------+---+----------+

//You can use column in partitionBy  that need to check for duplicate and also use respective orderBy also as of now I have use sample Window

scala> val W  = Window.partitionBy(col("ID"),col("CL_ID"),col("NBR"),col("DT"), col("TYP"), col("KEY")).orderBy(lit(1))

scala> df.withColumn("duplicate", when(row_number.over(W) === lit(1), lit("Y")).otherwise(lit("N")))
              .filter(col("duplicate") === lit("Y"))
              .drop("duplicate")
              .show()
+-------------------+--------------------+---+----------+---+----------+
|                 ID|               CL_ID|NBR|        DT|TYP|       KEY|
+-------------------+--------------------+---+----------+---+----------+
|1000031075_20190422|10017157594301072477| 10|2019-04-24|  N|0000000000|
|1006473016_20190421|10577157412800147475| 11|2019-04-21|  N|0000000000|
+-------------------+--------------------+---+----------+---+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your question that scales up well with big data :

```
df.dropDuplicates(include your key cols here = ID in this case).
```

Window function shuffles data, but if you have duplicate entries and want to choose which one to keep for example, or want to sum the value of the duplicates then window function is the way to go

```
w = Window.PartitionBy('id')
df.agg(first( value col ).over(w)) #you can use max, min, sum, first, last depending on how you want to treat duplicates
```

An interesting third possibility if you want to keep the values of duplicates (for record)
is the below before

```
df.withColumn('dup_values',  collect(value_col).over(w))
```

this will create an extra column with an array per row to keep duplicate values after you've got rid of the rows